# Binding da View para o Controller não funciona em campos "disabled"

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

Eu uso a propriedade `asp-for` nos elementos da minha `View` para passar os valores dos mesmos para o `Controller` na hora do `post` da página.

```
<input id="txtExamNumber" asp-for="ExamNumber" class="form-control" />
```

O que percebi é que se eu desativo o campo (`disabled`) através de `javascript`, o binding para o `Controller` não funciona mais. Em campos `hidden`, por exemplo, funciona perfeitamente.

Qual é a explicação para esse comportamento? Tem como contornar?

Answer (score 1):

Isso é um comportamento esperado por parte do formulário HTML, ele não manda os campos desabilitados (disabled), pois em teoria, quem os configurou assim não necessita deles no servidor.

Você pode substituir disabled por readonly.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp